# Making a class with a private constructor in F#

Tags: class, constructor, f#, private

I want to make a class that has **only** one constructor which is private. Now I know how to do it in C# but I can't figure out how to do it in F#.

Basically this is what I want to do in F#:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// A valid string is a string of 50 characters or less that contains only letters of the latin alphabet. 
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class ValidString {
        private readonly string _value;

        private ValidString(string value) {
            _value = value;
        }

        public string Value { get { return _value; } }

        public static bool TryParse(string input, out ValidString validStr) {
            bool valid = input.Length <= 50 && input.All(Char.IsLetter);
            validStr = valid ? new ValidString(input) : null;

            return valid;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The access specifier of the primary constructor follows the name and type parameters of the type:

```
type ValidString private (value: string) =
    ...
```